# Performing large queries on Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I'm working on a server built with Spring.
We have a very simple query (get all entities of a single kind) that fails to run after a certain threshold of records (~1,000,000).

This is the first method that I've tried (modified from the Google documentation):

```
PersistenceManager pm = persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();
List<T> Qresults;
List<T> detachedList =  new LinkedList<T>();
try {
    Query query = pm.newQuery(cla);
    query.setRange(0, 200);
    List<T> results = (List<T>) query.execute();
    Cursor cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(results);
    String cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();
    do {
        cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
        Map<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
        query.setExtensions(extensionMap);
        query.setRange(0, 200);
        Qresults = (List<T>) query.execute();
        results.addAll(Qresults);
    } while(Qresults.size() == 200);

    for (T item : results) {
        detachedList.add(pm.detachCopy(item));
    }
    return detachedList;
} finally {
    pm.close();
}
```

After that I've tried avoiding the PersistenceManager (I don't have any experience working with Spring or persistence):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Query q = new Query("MobileDevice");
FetchOptions options = FetchOptions.Builder.withChunkSize(1000);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

for (Entity result : pq.asIterable(options)) {
    array.put(new MobileDevice(result).toJSON());
}
return new transactionResult(array.toString());
```

The server threw a timeout exception on both cases.
Am I doing something wrong? Feels like this should be a simple operation.

Comment: I would recommend dividing your results and retrieving them in small chunks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeout is related to the time of the request execution, not to the number of entities. If you run this query on auto-scaled App Engine instances, you have 60 seconds to complete a request. There is also a limit on how long a datastore query remains available - you need to use cursors if the number of results is large.

The obvious solution is not to return a few million records as a single JSON object, but let the client (or whoever needs this data) get them in manageable chunks that take less than 60 seconds to retrieve.

Comment: He is using cursors already. So the solution would be to move the cursor string to the request parameters and response output, for the client to provide in the next query. Doesn't hurt to point that out more...

Comment: This sounds like what I need - but (forgot to mention this) how do I do it in a RESTful way? Do I need to serialize the point where I left off and send it to the client?

Comment: @JohnnyBack cursor.toWebSafeString() is websafe (obviously). You can add that to your response. I ususally create a Wrapper class for my responses which contains information like: was the action successful, are there more entries left, what is the cursor string, and of course the data itself.